# Nested private methods unit testing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, telerik, justmock

How do i write a just mocked unit test for this scenario?

```
Private Method1

{

  //calls private method - Method2
}
```

So that when i mock Method1, i need to again mock internally Method2.

I use form's private accessor to create a unit test, for ex.

```
FormName_accessor target=new FormName_accessor();
```

and then use that target.Method1 to call inside my unit test.

Comment: If you're mocking like this, what are you actually testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of mocking private methods of a class and verifying that they are called.

```
public class Item
{
    public void Update()
    {
        Save();
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        Validate();
        /// Save something
    }

    private void Validate()
    {
        /// Validate something
    }
}

[Fact]
public void EnsureNestedPrivateMethodsAreCalled()
{
    // Arrange
    Item item = Mock.Create<Item>();
    Mock.Arrange(() => item.Update()).CallOriginal().MustBeCalled();
    Mock.NonPublic.Arrange(item, "Save").CallOriginal().MustBeCalled();
    Mock.NonPublic.Arrange(item, "Validate").DoNothing().MustBeCalled();

    // Act
    item.Update();

    // Assert
    Mock.Assert(item);
}
```

Note that when arranging the mock you want to ensure that the original `Update` and `Save` methods are called. You only want to stub out functionality that you aren't testing. In this case, we are testing that calling `Update` results in calls to the private members `Save` and `Validate`. We are not testing the implementation of the `Validate` method.

Comment: say, `Update` contains some additional logic and finally calls `Save`. at this time, if i just want to test the implementation of `Update`, do i need to mock away the `Save`?